# How is segmentation different from multiprogramming with fixed partition?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, memory-access

As seen here:
It works same like multiprogramming with fixed partition and also the memory is contiguous as well. How is it different and especially non-contiguous? What's happening here?

Comment: Are you asking about x86 memory segmentation in real mode or something more general? What do you mean by "multiprogramming with fixed partition"?

Answer (score 2):

**Segmentation** partitions the address space into logically distinct parts
usually with the high-order bits representing the *segment number*, within which the low order bits are a normal linear address space.

A *segment* is the unit of access control to memory: one process may be able to read it while another is allowed to write it.

- A process will generally have access to many segments.
- Several processes may access the same segment. This is a possible way
  for processes to communicate.

In **Multiprogramming** with fixed partitions, each process occupies a contiguous linear address space. It may or may not be aware of the position of the address space in the computer's memory. The process has complete access to its own address space and no access to any other process's. Any process, however, may make system calls.

You can put paging (virtual memory) underneath segmented or partitioned memory.